# Subclass UICollectionViewTransitionLayout for automatic UINavigationViewController transition animation

Tags: ios, animation, layout, transition, collectionview

Is it possible to subclass `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` to change the automatic (e.g. non-interactive) animation when pushing/popping a view controller onto/off a `UINavigationController` stack?

Apples documentation and some articles in the internet suggest it should be possible:

> If you want to provide more than just a linear transition from the old to new layout over time, you need to subclass and provide the layout attributes for items yourself

…but I didn’t find a way yet.

I would like to use `UICollectionViewController`’s `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` to push one collection view controller on top of another (using the same data source). The two view controllers use different subclasses of `UICollectionViewLayout` which I want to transition using custom `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` that need to be keyframed and modified by the `transitionProgress`.

I was hoping, just implementing `collectionView:transitionLayoutForOldLayout:newLayout:` would do the trick, but that method only is called when transitioning interactively.

The best way I could come up with for the pushing is to call `startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:completion:` on the UICollectionView and pushing the new view controller without animation in the completion handler. For popping the view controller I would hook into `-viewWillDisappear:` of the view controller and check for the current view controller in the stack; if it is not there, I could again perform `startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:completion:`

Somehow I guess there is a better way…